# How to pass StartsWith() as a parameter to Expression.Call()?

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-4.0, expression-trees

Im trying to call StartsWith() function as an expression and pass a constant to it.

```
var textConstant =Expression.Constant(text);
var startsWith = Expression.Call(StartsWith ,textConstant); //something like this
```

Im new to c# and I couldn't figure out how to pass these into Expression.Call().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is sample:

```
 string text = "Some string";
 string startsText = "Some";
        
 Expression callExpr = Expression.Call(
                          Expression.Constant(text), 
                          typeof(String).GetMethod("StartsWith", 
                                         new Type[] { typeof(String) }),
                          Expression.Constant(startsText));
        
 // print the expression
 Console.WriteLine(callExpr);
        
 // execute the expression
 var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(callExpr).Compile();
 Console.WriteLine(lambda());
```

Comment: This works.Canyou also tell me what i am doing wrong trying to convert this lambda expression?
`customer => customer.ContactName.StartsWith("A")` 
I tried to do this:
`var customer = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer));
var customerContactName = Expression.PropertyOrField(customer, prop_2);
var textConstant = Expression.Constant(text);
Expression startsWith = Expression.Call(customerContactName,typeof(String).GetMethod("StartsWith",new Type[] { typeof(String) }), textConstant);
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> lambda_3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(startsWith, customer);`

Comment: @charthraxis: it may be good idea to open a new question to clarify that

Comment: Yes I realized this was not a clear question so I opened a new question. Can you check that out?